# First ping after ifup fails

Tags: debian, networking, ping

I have a weird issue on Debian 8 on a provisioning workflow,
the steps are :

- The debian is DHCP configured (from the PXEBoot)
- VLAN Change on ESX
- ifdown on eth0
- reconfigure /etc/network/interfaces with static address
- ifup on eth0
- ping -c 1 gateway

The gateway ping fails, but if you retry the ping it always succeed.
do you have any idea on why those first ping fail ?
No issue met on Debian 7 or RHEL 6 (maybe linked with systemd ?)
(I've tried added a 5 seconds -or 10 seconds- sleep before ping)
Thanks

Comment: How long does it take for `ping -c 1 gateway` to fail, and what's the full output? Which package is `ping` from (some versions of Debian include several slightly different implementations)?

Comment: @Gilles The ping output is simple : 1 paket transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms,  the version is : iputils-s20121221 (jessie)

Comment: Are you absolutely positively sure that the IP address isn't in use anywhere? What happens if you pick a different (also unused) IP address?

Comment: I'm absolutely positive, since I just need to retry for it to work perfectly (just launching ping a second time !)

Comment: That proves nothing: your machine could have grabbed the IP address in the router's ARP cache in the meantime. There may well be other reasons why it can't be an IP address conflict, but the information you've given so far is not conclusive.

Comment: You're right, the IP address may have been in use before by another machine, and the Gateway ARP Cache might be outdated, that would explain a lot, I'll take a look at the ARP Cache of the Gateway. One way to fix it would use arping and send gratuitous ARP, or reduce the ARP table timeout. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Before `ping` can send ICMP packets to the target host, it first decides whether it's a local or remote host.  Either way, it will need to retrieve the MAC address of the next hop, which could be the host itself on a local subnet or the router for a remote host.

It gets this using the Address Resolution Protocol (ARP) which in essence broadcasts *"Who has IP address a.b.c.d? Tell e.f.g.h"* and waits for a reply of *"IP address a.b.c.d is at MAC address ab-cd-ef-gh-ij-kl"*.  Once it has the MAC address it can send the ICMP packet.

The delay you're experiencing is due to this ARP process.  You can tell `ping` to wait longer with the `-W` option.

```
ping -W 10 gatway
```

will cause it to wait 10 seconds for a response.

ARP data is cached, therefore subsequent pings do not have to follow this process and the response is near instantaneous.

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't solve it, even if we try a `ping -c 4 -W 10 -I eth0 -n gateway`, still failure... the weird part is that if we clean the arp cache it doesn't fail again ...